# infoWindow de google maps no muestra el contenido

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estoy usando google maps y tengo un mapa donde tomo los markers de una base de datos y los muestro en el mapa, le agrego un `infoWindow` que se muestra cuando pulsan click sobre el marker, todo funciona bien, excepto que el `infowindow` aparece en blanco, sin texto.

He realizado pruebas con alert, me muestra el contenido correcto, e incluso lo coloco un texto fijo al contenido y sigue mostrando el infoWindow en blanco.

[image: imagen del infoWindow sin contenido]

```js
var map1;
var markers = [];
var locationSelect;
var coords = {};    //coordenadas obtenidas con la geolocalización

function initMap() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
   //usamos la API para geolocalizar el ususario
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
      coords  ={
        lat : position.coords.latitude,
        lng : position.coords.longitude
      }
      carga(coords);
    }, mostrarErrores);
  }
  else{
    alert('Oops! Tu navegador no soporta geolocalización. Bájate Chrome, que es gratis! ;(');
  }
}

function mostrarErrores(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        alert('Permiso denegado por el usuario'); 
        break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        alert('Posición no disponible');
        break; 
    case error.TIMEOUT:
        alert('Tiempo de espera agotado');
        break;
    default:
        alert('Error de Geolocalización desconocido :' + error.code);
  }
}

function carga(coords){
  map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'),
  {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng),
    mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var radius = 25;
  var searchUrl = 'php/escenarios-cerca.php?lat=' + coords.lat + '&lng=' + coords.lng + '&radius=' + radius;
// carga markers
  downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
    var xml = parseXml(data);

    var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var n = markerNodes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("nombre");
      var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("direccion");
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      createMarker(latlng, name, address);
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map1,
    title: "Escenario "+name  
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b><br>" + address;
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});
    infoWindow.open(map1, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request.responseText, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url);
  request.send(null);
}

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } 
  else 
    if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
    }
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si realmente hay texto dentro, y éste aparece con las letras en color blanco y por eso no aparece?

Comment: Hola, por favor edita la pregunta y agrega una muestra del XML. Gracias!

Comment: Probaste Inpeccionar el código a ver si esta ahi?. Proba cambiar el código y en lugar de `var html = "<b>" + name + "</b><br>" + address;` pone: `var html = "<span style="color: black !important;"><b>" + name + "</b><br>" + address + "</span>;"`

Comment: Efectivamente, al hacer el cambio de style="color : black" ya mostró el texto. Muchas gracias por sus aoprtes

Comment: @ArielRey debieras copiar tu comentario a respuesta para que el que hizo la pregunta pueda marcarla como respondida.

Answer (score 1):

Probaste Inpeccionar el código a ver si esta ahi?. Proba cambiar el código y en lugar de `var html = "<b>" + name + "</b><br>" + address; pone: var html = "<span style="color: black !important;"><b>" + name + "</b><br>" + address + "</span>;"`